# How to get the Arabic text using TBXML parser?

Tags: iphone, ios, xml-parsing, tbxml

I have Arabic text in XML as shown below.

Code:

```
NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc]
                    initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] //webData has received data
                    length:[webData length]
                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];         
NSLog(@"result %@",theXML);
```

NSLog Result:

```
 <media:title type='plain'>أحبج يا كويت</media:title>
```

After parsing using TBXML parser

Code:

```
 if ([[TBXML attributeName:attribute] isEqualToString:@"type"]
      &&[[TBXML elementName:element] isEqualToString:@"media:title"])
            {
                NSLog(@"%s",element->text);
            }
```

I am getting this

NSLog Result:

```
  ÿ®ÿ±ŸÜÿßŸÖÿ¨ ÿ™ŸàŸäÿ™ÿ± ÿ±ŸÖÿ∂ÿßŸÜŸä ÿ≠4 [ ÿÆŸÑŸÉ ÿ≠ÿ∂ÿßÿ±Ÿä ]
```

I need it to be in Arabic not the text as shown above.

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: check your system is supporting arabic font which u get in your xml file, You can check by searching for  Font book in spotlight of mac. You no need to do anything in program.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but that is not a solution. I already have many Arabic fonts installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it myself after one day efforts, answer lies in

```
[TBXML textForElement:element] // Method
```

instead of

```
element->text.
```

Hope it will helps for other users in coming future.